# Distinguish between `onStop` in different situations

Tags: android

Is it possbile to distinguish in `onStop`(in `Fragment`) method two situation:

1. The phone was rotated  (onConfigChanged)
2. The home button was pressed / The activity was finished and so on.

What I have to do:

When the activity become invisible ( like `Home pressed`, open another activity, onBackPressed) I have to do some action. ( Clear some information).

Comment: You can create a bool, set to true in the onConfigChanged and check it in the onStop. But probably you are doing something that you should not be doing in the onStop method. Please add to your question what you need to do.

Comment: You have the isChangingConfiguration() and isFinishing() methods available in the Activity which could help.

Comment: @jonathanrz, I edited.

Comment: @J.Doe probably you should put this information inside the onSaveInstance and clean the information always. The app should not behave differently when opened or rotated the device.